# Parse and create associative array from inline style values with Regex PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have such an inline CSS like this

```
text-align:center; float:left;width:18%;
```

Expectation

```
Array
(
    [text-align] => center
    [float] => left
    [width] => 18%

)
```

Can anybody suggest me a way to use regular expression to complete this task?

Comment: The problem? Do you encounter any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
$r = array();
preg_match_all("/([\w-]+)\s*:\s*([^;]+)\s*;?/", 'text-align:center; float:left;width:18%;', $arr, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($arr as $v) {
  $r[$v[1]] = $v[2];
}
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/qxanGV/1/

Add explain usage https://regexr.com/3tcik